# Moving Thunderbird from Windows XP to Mac OS X (Snow Leopard)

Tags: windows-xp, osx-snow-leopard, thunderbird, ntfs

I am trying to move my Thunderbird profile from Windows XP to Macintosh Snow Leopard 10.6.7.  I took my Windows drive and put it into an USB drive and mounted it on my Mac.  I could not see my Application Data special folder on the Mac, but it seems to have copied the whole drive given the size is 16GB, but none of the visible folders are anywhere near that size.

How can I see the hidden Application Data folder that I think is now copied to my Mac drive?

Once I get this, I think I can reuse the profile for Thunderbird on the Mac, hopefully that is correct, can you confirm?

Comment: I don't really understand what you did exactly. Basically you want to copy `C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\Thunderbird\Profiles\<profile>` to `/Users/<user>/Library/Application Support/Thunderbird/Profiles/<profile>/`. Do you mean you can't see the first? How did you "take your Windows drive and put it into an USB drive"? What do you see on the drive when it's mounted?

Comment: Yes could not see the first so had copied parent directory. USB drive mounted as `Untitled` with USB icon of drive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked around issue by moving Thunderbird profiles folder out of special `Application Data` folder to the root of the USB drive back on the Windows XP machine. Then I could see and copy it fine on Mac and place it in Mac location for Thunderbird profiles.

I was also able to find original hidden folder using search tool on Mac.  Somehow the copied `Application Data` folder is hidden when copy to Mac but search can locate it.

All is working in Thunderbird now with my XP profile now on Mac.